# Is there a way to use Object Destructuring in ES2105 to prune an object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Currently, when I want to prune an object (say, a user object that has details I don't want to send to the client), I have been copying over properties like so:

```
let user = db.findUser(_id);
//user = { username: "John", hashedPassword: "ashHDhadh23hfJAd", email: "John@doe.com", created: "<some date>" ... }
let forClient = {
    username: user.username,
    email: user.email
}
...
```

I am learning about destructuring an object in ES2015 and it seems like it might be possible to do this more cleanly. Is it?

Comment: Not certain how destructuring would assign properties, values "more cleanly" than current `js` ?

Comment: Destructuring makes it easy to extract properties into variables. I don't think it helps with object-to-object assignment.

Comment: ES2015 would help you to get cleaner code, but anyway, the best way here is using some library, for example, lodash has a [pick](https://lodash.com/docs#pick) function: `userForClient = _.pick(user, ['username', 'email'])`

Answer (score 1):

Destructuring won't help here without introducing overhead. It simplifies creating variables from an object, i.e. if you would use it here, it result in something like this:

```js
let { username, email } = user;
let forClient = { username, email };
```

But as you can see, this adds new variables and repeats code.

You could consider using reduce to select the wanted fields:

```js
let forClient = ['username', 'email'].reduce((v, k) => { v[k] = user[k]; return v }, {});
```

... or with a higher-order function to not repeat too much code:

```js
const selectFrom = (obj) => (v, k) => { v[k] = obj[k]; return v };

let userForClient = ['username', 'email'].reduce(selectFrom(user), {});
let postForClient = ['title', 'summary'].reduce(selectFrom(blogpost), {});
// etc.
```

... or just add a function like this to your library, which uses the [rest spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for simple usage:

```js
function pruneObject(obj, ...fields) {
  let pruned = {};
  fields.forEach(f => pruned[f] = obj[f]);
  return pruned;
}

let forClient = pruneObject(user, 'username', 'email');
```

Comment: Yes, I am currently using a helper similar to your pruneObject(obj, ...fields) function, but I was hoping for there to be a destructuring approach to this problem. Also, I think you meant `obj[f]` and not `user[f]`, right?